# How to use Query in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to find some data from Firebase and I have a problem with filtering this data. My database model looks like that:
[image]

I try to check if in "adds" is an add where "title" is equal some another title

```
func isExistingAdd(title: String, @escaping bool: (Bool) -> ()) {   
reference.child("adds").queryOrdered(byChild: "title").queryEqual(toValue: title).observe(.childAdded) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        print("SNAP VALUE: \(snap.value)")
        if let _ = snap.value as? [String: Any] {
            bool(true)
        } else {
            bool(false)
        }
    }
}
```

in this case I receive only one result if in database is more than one or when is no results I receive this info:
`Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "title" at /users/JNF7Ny5cegfMzsZBRZAtB4tm1c33/adds to your security rules for better performance`, any ideas how can I filter data in "adds" and find adds with specific title which is interesting for me?

Comment: thats fine I think and that warning is just to suggest you that by define that rule you may get better performance for your app

Comment: You mean if you having multiple entry with same title or there is no entry with your searching title you are getting this warning?

Comment: this warning is when is no entry with searching title